# Modify payload field values

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I have incoming payload as follow:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "provision": {
        "switch": "xyz",
        "port": ""
    }
}
```

I want to transform this payload so that **id** gets set to **9** and **port** to **80**. So after the transform the payload should be

```
{
    "id": "9",
    "provision": {
        "switch": "xyz",
        "port": "80"
    }
}
```

How can I do this? I am using EE 4.2.2

Comment: Where do you get the value 9 and 80 from ? What is the source/logic for that information?

Comment: Hardcoded for now. It can potentially come from attributes collection field too. I am just trying to figure out how can existing payload values can be modified. Trying different syntaxes but none work so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the update operator.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-values-functions-update

**Input**

```
{
    "id": "",
    "provision": {
        "switch": "xyz",
        "port": ""
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
(payload update field("id") with 9) update ["provision",field("port")] with 80
```

**Output**

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "provision": {
    "switch": "xyz",
    "port": 80
  }
}
```

Comment: I try it without any luck so far. Given my version is 4.2.2, I was not sure if I can even use it. Can you provide an example of the transform?

Comment: i see you are on 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Another crude approach. Not recommended..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var id = payload - "provision"
var provision = payload - "id"
var newProv= provision[0] - "port" ++ {"port" : 80}

---
{id:9} ++ provision : newProv
```